# I have a error with “NGINX Ingress controller” in Kubernetes when “Invalid header field value”

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We are instaling and configuring "NGINX Ingress controller" but we are encountring some problems when Nginx invoke to apiserver at startup:

> Invalid header field value "Bearer d754141a94bb6499e284da0e2639e77e\n" for key Authorization.

The bearer appears with a "\n" ¿?¿? but in our token file seems ok. Can someone help us? We do not know what may be happening since our token is correct (we can invoke via curl from outside).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the RBAC for NGINX Ingress controller?

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/575

the reference maybe help you, good luck